# mysql doesn't like my statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to call book details from the relationships table in my database, mysql is throwing an error with the syntax of the code. The previous page is

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>Retrieve Relationships</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <dl>

    <?php
    // Connect to database server
    mysql_connect("localhost","","") or die (mysql_error ());

    // Select database
    mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

    // Get data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL
    $title = (isset($_GET['title']) && is_string($_GET['title'])) ? $_GET['title'] : null;
$sTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$strSQL = "SELECT relationships.bookone, relationships.booktwo, relationships.relationship
FROM relationships, books
WHERE books.bookid=relationships.bookone AND relationships.bookone='{$sTitle}'";
     $rs = mysql_query($strSQL)
    // Loop the recordset $rs

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

        // Write the data of the person
        echo "<dt>Book One:</dt><dd>" . $row["bookone"] . "</dd>";
        echo "<dt>Book Two:</dt><dd>" . $row["booktwo"] . "</dd>";
        echo "<dt>Relationship:</dt><dd>" . $row["relationship"] . "</dd>";
        echo "<dt>Likes:</dt><dd>" . $row["relationshiplikes"] . "</dd>";
        echo "<dt>Dislikes:</dt><dd>" . $row["relationshipdislikes"] . "</dd>";

    }

    // Close the database connection
    mysql_close();
    ?>

    </dl>
    <p><a href="search.php">Return to the list</a></p>

    </body>

    </html>
```

what im trying to get the page to display is the bookone's code and booktwo's code where bookones id = booksid

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Change to `$rs = mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());` and see what it says

Comment: The variable you're putting into the query needs to be in single quotes if it's a string.  Also, your code is open to SQL injection.

Comment: You didn't close this single quote in your query: `'{$sTitle}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT relationships.bookone, relationships.booktwo, relationships.relationship
FROM relationships, books
WHERE books.bookid=relationships.bookone AND relationships.bookone='{$_GET['bookone']}'";
```

Though, *really*, it should be:

```
$title = (isset($_GET['title']) && is_string($_GET['title'])) ? $_GET['title'] : null;
$sTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$strSQL = "SELECT relationships.bookone, relationships.booktwo, relationships.relationship
FROM relationships, books
WHERE books.bookid=relationships.bookone AND relationships.bookone='{$sTitle}'";
```

[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is rather bad :).

(Not to mention that it would also harmlessly break if a user searched for a book with an apostrophe in the title.)

Comment: its now throwing an issue with this line of code, saying Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sTitle) or die(mysql_error()))

Comment: @user1393064 You still need to pass $rs to mysql_fetch_array, not $sTitle.  $sTitle contains the escaped title, not the query resource that mysql_fetch_array needs.

Comment: I had %rs before but it threw an undefined error

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `$rs` and not `%rs`?  And if they're defined in the same scope, it shouldn't do that.

Comment: check the the original post for updated code

Comment: You no longer have the $rs = mysql_query($strSQL) in there.  How would it be defined if it's literally not even in the file?  Also, `$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs) or die(mysql_error())` is wrong.  mysql_fetch_array returns false once the resource has no more rows, so basically once that loop ends, the program is going to die.

Comment: sorry im very new to php, and haven't had a chance to do basic tutorials because I've been forced to learn cakephp

Comment: CakePHP can be quite a thing to learn.  I suggest that you learn the basics very well first.  But anyway, I just edited my answer.  As someone pointed out in a comment on the question, I missed a single quote in my query string.

Comment: im finding cakePHP a bit easier than php, it makes more sense(to me :/)

i just updated my code and am getting an error with the while loop?

Comment: @user1393064 I'm sorry, but I can't teach you PHP one error at a time.  Find a good PHP/MySQL tutorial, and learn the basics.  (Also I suggest you switch to PDO over the ancient mysql_* API.)  Anyway, if it says it was expecting a resource, it means the query failed, and you need to check why with mysql_error().

Comment: missed a semi-colom thanks for your help mate, I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not need a join for this table. You are not actually using the books table at all. It looks like all you need is:

```
SELECT r.bookone, r.booktwo, r.relationship FROM relationships AS r WHERE r.bookone='{$sTitle}'
```

But later you are using columns `relationshiplikes` and `relationshipdislikes` which you are not picking up with this query. So maybe what you really want is this:

```
SELECT r.* FROM relationships AS r WHERE r.bookone='{$sTitle}'
```

Comment: once I get bookone and booktwo working i plan on adding the rest

Comment: Is it that you need the whole relationships row? Then just `SELECT r.*` instead of these specific columns.

Comment: there is a relationshipid that i do not want displayed, its only in the system for database purposes

Comment: Besides, you should always only get what you absolutely need, always avoid *.

Comment: ^ Disagree with 'always'